# How to resize a PNG print for the KR403 printer?

Tags: android, bitmap, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl

I can currently print a PNG file through the ZPL commands on my Zebra KR403 printer.

The issue I currently face is that the size of the print is too small. Is there a way to rescale the print size  on the paper w/o rescaling the actual PNG file using a ZPL command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the using the ^A command. Format: ^Afo,h,w

f is font name, o is orientation h and w are height and width.

You can look for examples in the zpl manual. which i'd be happy to provide if you need it